# Is there a pre-defined color list? so I could access the colors by index

Tags: python

I was wondering if there is a pre-defined color list.
For example `colors = ['red', 'orange', 'yellow'...]`

I wanted assign items with colors, However **the number of items** is not set and is unknown.

 So I was trying to set a code such as

```
color_dict = {}
for num, i in enumerate(list_with_random_items):
    color_dict[i] = colors[num]
```

Is creating my own list of colors (ex. `colors=['red', 'yellow']`) the only way?

Comment: Python has no such list built in. You may find a list of color names somewhere on the internet which can then be converted to a Python list.

Comment: Make the key point to a tuple of rgb values. I.e. `color_dict = {"white": (255, 255, 255), "black": (0, 0, 0)}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used `matplotlib.colors`

```
import matplotlib.colors as mcl

mcl.BASE_COLORS

mcl.TABLEAU_COLORS
```

gives the following output:

```
{'b': (0, 0, 1),
 'g': (0, 0.5, 0),
 'r': (1, 0, 0),
 'c': (0, 0.75, 0.75),
 'm': (0.75, 0, 0.75),
 'y': (0.75, 0.75, 0),
 'k': (0, 0, 0),
 'w': (1, 1, 1)}

==========================

OrderedDict([('tab:blue', '#1f77b4'),
             ('tab:orange', '#ff7f0e'),
             ('tab:green', '#2ca02c'),
             ('tab:red', '#d62728'),
             ('tab:purple', '#9467bd'),
             ('tab:brown', '#8c564b'),
             ('tab:pink', '#e377c2'),
             ('tab:gray', '#7f7f7f'),
             ('tab:olive', '#bcbd22'),
             ('tab:cyan', '#17becf')])
```

and just used the keys of it

Comment: Clever solution. Kind of awkward though since you're combining two different lists with completely different representations.